# Why doesn't task manager show the publisher column when i have signed an executable with signtool

Tags: visual-studio, certificate, signtool

I use Visual Studio 2017 to create an executable, then signtool to sign it, using a certificate from sectigo.

```
signtool.exe sign /f $key /p $pass $file

signtool.exe verify /v /pa $file
```

But when i run the executable and open the task manager (and add in the publisher column to the list of columns to show) the publisher shows up as blank. I would have thought the publisher would be taken from the certificate.

Thanks for any help anyone can give.